# Do you implement behaviour for all the segues of one view controller in the same prepareForSegue method?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm to understand how prepareForSegue works for different types of segues in a single view controller...I mean, it's possible that a view controller would have different types of segues in a single view and implement a different tasks for each of them in the prepareForSegue method, so is it all going in the same one?

I understand that each segue you define would send a segue objects to the prepareForSegue method, but how the method knows which code to preform?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will do all of your logic for segues for that view controller in that single function.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Prepare for segue: %@", [segue identifier]);
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue1"]) {
        // logic for segue 1
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue2"]) {
        // logic for segue 2
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue3"]) {
        // logic for segue 3
    }
}
```